# logical indexing in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, logical-operators

I am a beginner in data.table and I am trying to do a really simple operation which in the base dataframes would look like this:

```
percentages[percentages<0] = abs(percentages[percentages<0])
```

The data looks like this:

```
percentages

  p1    p2    p3
1: 0.689 0.206 0.106
```

The solution for data.table that I have found so far to just get the data is:

```
percentages[,which(percentages<0),with=FALSE]
```

but it's more complicated than dataframe...there should be something better but I can't get anything.. any suggestion?

Comment: Please show few lines of dataset and the expected output

Comment: You may not need `which`, but for subsetting data.table, `with=FALSE` is needed.  Also, insted of percentages, it would be `.SD`

Comment: ok thanks for that, just tried your suggestion and it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: > percentages$p1=-0.54
> percentages[,.SD<0,with=FALSE]
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)

Comment: Do you have only a single row as in the example?  Anyway, `df1[, df1[, .SD < 0], with = FALSE]` seems to work or `df1[, sapply(df1, "<", 0), with = FALSE]`

Comment: Okay, so if I understand you correctly you want to assign the absolute values to all negative values anywhere in the data.table?

Comment: Bcz the question is not clear and there is no expected output.  I thought you want to subset the columns

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as akrun posted above, the one-liner reply is

```
df1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x < 0, abs(x)))]
```

however, this is not exactly what I was looking for since it seems that data.table is much more syntactically complicated compared to data.frame (at least in this example)

we are basically doing the vectorization ourselves in data.table (using the lapply) while in data.frame it happens automatically

Comment: I down voted your answer because you're using @akrun's answer , which apparently you didn't very read carefully.

Comment: @rafa.pereira apparently you didn't read my initial question... you can down vote whatever you want but it's not a bad idea to first read what is written in the initial point (which is about syntactic complexity)

Comment: I've read your question and I understand your point. Perhaps, however, you think this is a complicated syntax because you're new to `data.table` as you mentioned. I my self agree that the `set` loop does look complicated at first. My point with the down vote is that it is not good practice to take credit for someone else's answer, you could have been more polite in other comments in the whole discussion and your question could have been more clear, preferably with a reproducible example and expected output . all the best, Rafa

Comment: @rafa.pereira: 1. Your accusation of myself taking credit for someone else makes no sense... I did clearly mention his name 2. I have remained polite even now with your irrelevant accusations 3. The question was a basic operation and it was reproducible in R with the base package. 4. you might be missing that lapply or replace are not part of the data.table package so it's not about the fact that I am new to the package that I state that the syntax seems more complicated... it is just more complicated...

Answer (score 2):

A general option may be using `set`.  It includes a `for` loop but it would be more efficient as we are looping through the columns and not creating a `matrix` by doing (`df1 < 0` - for huge datasets, this would consume some memory).  Using `set` will be efficient as the documentation says overhead of `[.data.table` is avoided

```
for(j in seq_along(df1)){
  set(df1, i = which(df1[[j]]<0), j=j, value = abs(df1[[j]]))
}
```

As the OP wants a single line code, for the single row example showed,

```
df1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x < 0, abs(x)))]
```

#### Benchmarks

Based on the `system.time` on a slightly bigger dataset

```
 set.seed(42)
 dfN <- data.frame(p1 = rnorm(1e7), p2 = rnorm(1e7), p3 = rnorm(1e7), p4 = rnorm(1e7))

dfN1 <- copy(dfN)
setDT(dfN1)
system.time({
  i1 <- dfN < 0
  dfN[i1] <- abs(dfN[i1])
})

#  user  system elapsed 
#  1.63    0.50    2.12 

system.time({
 for(j in seq_along(dfN1)){
  set(dfN1, i = which(dfN1[[j]]<0), j=j, value = abs(dfN1[[j]][dfN1[[j]]<0]))
 }
})

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.91    0.08    0.98
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but if in the base dataframe it's a vectorized operation, adding a for-loop in the 'data.table world' is something that I am trying to avoid

Comment: @sen_saven Please read the answer and also check the `?set` help page

Comment: I repeat, in dataframe I would do that in one line, is there is a similar one-line solution in data.table yes or no?... I had in mind that there is one, but if not, it is what it is...

Comment: @sen_saven It is an efficient solution that is what data.table is used for.  You can do several things in base R in a single line, For example, if you are doing a group by operation with `aggregate`, it is very compact, but it may not be that efficient with big datasets.

Comment: so data.table is meant to make things faster but on the expense of making the code less readable/compact... there is no solution to my initial question...

Comment: @sen_saven It depends on the person who is reading.  For me, the code is readable.

Comment: Another option is melting the data.table since it should probably be in long format anyway. Or use a `matrix` instead of a data.table/data.frame.

Comment: It's not too bad for me either, but I have been taught to try and code in a way that a five year old child will get it... anyway, thanks for your help